# URL from get_post_meta() is broken my URL

Tags: post-meta

I'm just another biginner on PHP and wordpress. Well, I've used another code to get meta data and use it as a link in my blog. Everything is fine, but the link is incorrect, wordpress add the website URL and my meta_data URL.

I'm using the code posted here: [adding a URL to a post meta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17501/adding-a-url-to-a-post-meta)

```
 <?php
  if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, "Link", true ) ){
    echo '<div class="pros"><p><strong>Movie Website:  </strong><a href="' .
    get_post_meta( $post->ID, "Link", true ) .
    '" target="_blank">' .
    get_post_meta( $post->ID, "Link", true ) .
    '</a></p></div>';
  }
?>
```

For exemplo:
I've got "www.stackexchange.com" from my post.
When I use this funcion to put this data into my blog, it came as "localhost/mysite.com/www.stackexchange.com"

Is anybody can help me?

[image]

Comment: You left out `http://`.

Comment: Yep, you'd have to insert the full URL in the postmeta for the link to work. Without "http" or "https" any browser is going to assume it's a relative link and put localhost at the beginning.

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie It worked. Thank you very much. Now, Is there a way to add a direct link to whatsapp api?

Comment: @WebElaine thhka you, It worked.